# Find and replace Array values recursively by sub-arrays present within the Array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I have a JSON which looks like below example:

```
{
  "a": {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "test",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "b",
        "type": "b"
      }
    ]
  },
  "d": {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "d"
  },
  "c": {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "b",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "d",
        "type": "d"
      }
    ]
  },
  "b": {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Core",
    
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "test",
        "type": "c"
      },
      {
        "name": "testMulti",
        "type": [
          "null",
          "c"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Recursively, in this array, there is a `key` named `type`. For example, `"type" => "b"`. I am looking for an approach to find `$key == 'type'` and replace the `value` of the `key` with the `value` of the `key` with the same name.

For example, In the sub-array `a`, where `"type" => "b"`, the code should replace the value of the key `b`, i.e. the sub-array `b` and so on.

After the search and replace it should look like this.

```
{
  "a": {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "test",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "b",
        "type": {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "Core",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "test",
              "type": {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "b",
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "name": "d",
                    "type": {
                      "type": "record",
                      "name": "d"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "testMulti",
              "type": [
                "null",
                {
                  "type": "record",
                  "name": "b",
                  "fields": [
                    {
                      "name": "d",
                      "type": {
                        "type": "record",
                        "name": "d"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see that all the types were replaced by the values of the keys.
For example, `"type" => "b"` was replaced by the value `"b"` an so on.

I have created a function that uses recursion to traverse all the keys, but I got stuck to merge the sub-arrays back into one complete array.

```
private function mergeSchema($schemaArray) {
        foreach ($schemaArray as $key => $value) {
            // p_r($key, $value);
            if(is_array($value)) {
                // echo 'in array' . PHP_EOL;
                $schemaArray = $this->mergeSchema($value);
            }
            if($key == 'type' && !(is_named_type($value) || is_primitive_type($value))) {
                p_R($value);
            }
        }
        return $schemaArray;
    }
```

```
public static function is_named_type($type)
  {
    return in_array($type, self::$named_types);
  }
public static function is_primitive_type($type)
  {
    return in_array($type, self::$primitive_types);
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Comment: Can you explain better what should be replaced with what in a small example?

Comment: Sure I can; I'll edit my example. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have updated my question. I hope it is more understandable now.

Comment: Do you use `json_decode`?

Comment: Yep. I do. I didn't mention it here as I thought it was implied.